# Check variable is null in if condition

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func
RETURN varchar2 AS
myvar INT;
BEGIN
  select 1 into myvar  from dual where 1=2;
  IF  myvar  IS NULL THEN
    return 'n';
  ELSE
    return 'y';
  END IF;
END;


SELECT  func() FROM DUAL;
```

Why this function returns `NULL` instead of  string "n" ?

Comment: because you´re getting an exception as of `no_data_found` (`insert into` wont get any data here and this will raise the exception)and as though no return happens => `null` as return

Comment: SomeJavaGuy nailed it. A `SELECT ... INTO ... ` statement in PL/SQL must return exactly one row, otherwise it raises an exception: `NO_DATA_FOUND` if it returned no rows, `TOO_MANY_ROWS` if it returned two or more rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you´re getting an exception as of `no_data_found` (`insert into` wont get any data here and this will raise the exception) and as though no return happens => `null` as return:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func
RETURN varchar2 AS
myvar INT;
BEGIN
  select 1 into myvar  from dual where 1=2;
  IF  myvar  IS NULL THEN
    return 'n';
  ELSE
    return 'y';
  END IF;
-- This will execute now
exception 
   when no_data_found then
      return 'no_data_found';
   -- Just to note, when it has 2 rows+ that´s the other possible exception here
   when to_many_rows then
      return 'to_many_rows';
END;
/
SELECT func() FROM DUAL;
```

O/P

```
no_data_found
```